# Difference between not in and in with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null

I stumbled upon some old code in our DB that behaved not as expected. I managed to narrow it down to effect of `NULL` value for `IN` clause.

I derived a test that demonstrates it:

```sql
declare @test   nvarchar(50) = '8620M/9010';
declare @testLT nvarchar(50) = '8004/9010';
declare @testLV nvarchar(50) =  null;  --'asd'
select case when @test not in (@testLT, @testLV) then 1 else 0 end
```

If testLV is null, `NOT IN` returns same result as `IN` clause.

I want to understand the mechanism behind this behavior. Can somebody explain ?

Ps. I will probably replace it with `EXCEPT` clause

Comment: How you can say that something is IN or NOT IN something else, if you don't know what it is? If you'd prepend [`SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) you would get your expected result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The semantics of `NOT IN` are affected by having a `NULL` value in the list.  In SQL, `NULL` means "I don't know the value; it could be anything.".

So, if you do:

```
where 1 in (1, 2)
```

then it returns true.

```
where 1 in (3, 4)
```

returns false.

So far, so good.  Now consider:

```
where 1 not in (1, 2, NULL)
```

Well, "1" is clearly in the list.  So this returns false.

```
where 1 not in (3, 4, NULL)
```

Well, "1" is not "3" or "4".  But is it `NULL`?  We don't know.  So, this returns `NULL` rather than true.  And `NULL` is treated the same as false in a `WHERE` condition, meaning that the row is filtered out. (As a note:  `check` conditions behave differently, with only *explicit* false's failing the `check`.)

So, nothing is returned with `NOT IN` if *any* of the values are `NULL`.

This situation almost always comes up in the context of subqueries (rather than constants).  For this reason, I recommend using `NOT EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN` in all cases with a subquery.

Comment: `So, this returns NULL rather than true. And NULL is treated the same as false in a WHERE condition.` Three-valued logic: True, False, Unknown,

Comment: This three valued logic is the reason of my question, I assumed comparison works  like in C#.

Answer (score 3):

[IN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> Caution
>
> Any null values returned by subquery or expression that are compared
>   to test_expression using IN or NOT IN return UNKNOWN. Using null
>   values in together with IN or NOT IN can produce unexpected results.

UNKNOWN <> TRUE

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` means I don't know, which is an absence value.

In your case `IN` will translate to

```
@test = @testLT or @test =@testLV
```

In your case `NOT IN` will translate to

```
@test <> @testLT or @test <> @testLV
```

But `NULL` can't use `<>` or `=` to get the value when the `ANSI_NULLS` set `ON`.

Comment: `@test = @testLT and @test =@testLV` did you mean `or` in there?

Comment: `But NULL can't use <> or = to get the value.` ANSI_NULLS OFF?

Comment: @TaPaKaHUA Thanks for reminding me that this is my fault.
Because `ANSI_NULLS` is generally `on`, so I forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Caution
>
> Any null values returned by subquery or expression that are compared to test_expression
> using IN or NOT IN return UNKNOWN. Using null values in together with IN or NOT IN can produce unexpected results.

The comparison between @test and @testLV will always return "UNKNOWN" instead of TRUE or FALSE.